# Converting from GooglePlayService GCM to FireBaseMessaging in Xamarin.Android no registration

Tags: firebase, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've inherited a Xamarin Android project that uses push notifications.  The project was using the Google Client Messaging package, I am in the process of converting to the Firebase Messaging package.  But I've noticed that there is no .register method for FireBaseMessaging.  Do I still need to register with the sender id from the firebase console and if so how?

Old Code:

```
    private void registerInBackground()
    {

        Task.Run(() =>
            {
                string msg = "";
                try
                {
                    if (gcm == null)
                    {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.GetInstance(this);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.Register(Constants.SenderID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                    Log.Info(TAG, msg);


                    // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend(regid);


                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(this, regid);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.Message;

                    Log.Error(TAG, msg);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //RunOnUiThread(() => mDisplay.Append(msg + "\n"));
                }
                return msg;
            });
    }
```

When I change to FireBaseMessaging I notice that on the line regid = gcm.Register(Constants.SenderID); there is no register method on Firebase messaging.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call a register method it will automatically register. You just need to follow this steps:

1. Add google-services.json to the Android project and make sure to set the build action of that file as GoogleServicesJson.
2. Add the following in AndroidManifest.xml under application tag:

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
   <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" 
         android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
     <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
   </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
3. Implement FirebaseInstanceIdService

   ```
   [Service, IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
   public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
   {
      public override void OnTokenRefresh()
      {

        var token = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        //send token to server here.
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Do I need to call the FireBaseInstanceID class at all or is this a callback?

Comment: Don't it to call it will get called automatically by Android

Comment: As you can see is a Service with an IntentFilter so once token is ready will get called.